# shortcode inside another shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I wonder if is it possible to have a shortcode inside another one?

My scenario is this:

I create a shortcodes to display content into columns so I can manage the layout of the page more easily. Now the problem comes, when I try to use for sample nextgen gallery into one of those shortcodes. For some reason it just generates the shortcode as plain text.

Any idea why?

I will show you the code I'm using for the shortcode maybe it helps:

```
 // Column ShortCode Description
function column_scdescription($atts, $content="null") {
    return '<div class="description">' .$content . '</div> <!-- description ends here -->';
}
add_shortcode ("product-description", "column_scdescription");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually apply the_content filters to $content to do this. I think you can aslo use do_shortcode($content);

```
// Column ShortCode Description
function column_scdescription($atts, $content="null") {
    return '<div class="description">' .apply_filters('the_content', $content) . '</div> <!-- description ends here -->';
}
add_shortcode ("product-description", "column_scdescription");
```

Read up on [Nested Shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes) in the codex.

Answer (score 4):

'you can use the [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) wp function

```
function column_scdescription($atts, $content="null") {
    return '<div class="description">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode ("product-description", "column_scdescription");
```

Comment: does it work only if inside there is a shortcode right? if there plain text would it work? thanks for answer!

Comment: if there isn't a shortcode inside it will return as plain text.