# Custom shortcode is not working inside tabs

Tags: shortcode

Not able run the shortcode. Created to show custom post type pages inside Tabs created by a plugin. I have attached the image for the same with this post.

[image]

Here is code I have created.

```
<?php 
 function casino_bros() {    
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
     $args=array(
       'post_type'=>casino,              
       'posts_per_page' => 5,
       'orderby' => 'date',
       'paged'=>$paged
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    /* PageNavi at Top */

    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();   

    /* DO STUFF IN THE LOOP */
    ?>
            /*  Post Loop   */

    <?php
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query(); ?> 

<?php } 

add_shortcode( 'livecasinoss', 'casino_bros' );  
function some_func()
{
    $data=('[livecasinoss]');    
    return do_shortcode($data); 
} 
add_shortcode( 'livecasinos', 'some_func' );?>
```

Comment: What created the tabs? How do the tabs work? You will need to post the relevant code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shortcode inside another shortcode](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35208/shortcode-inside-another-shortcode)

Comment: tabs are created by a plugin , but the inner short-codes are my own created . I need content in all tabs through my short code

Comment: Above black border content need to be inside the tab .. but it's appearing before tab.

Comment: I am not a expert in programming but can create some basic codes:-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the article shows, [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) can capture typical loop output and return as a variable. When you're in the loop you might want to make sure the_content renders it's shortcode as well.

```
function do_livecasinoss_shortcode($atts, $content = "") {

    // start the buffer
    ob_start();

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'casino',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'paged'          => $paged,
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    /* PageNavi at Top */

    if($wp_query->have_posts()) : while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

        /* DO STUFF IN THE LOOP */

        // run any shortcode items inside the_content
        echo apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());

        ?>/*  Post Loop   */<?php

    endwhile; endif;

    wp_reset_query();

    // stop the buffer / capture and return the output
    return obj_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('livecasinoss', 'do_livecasinoss_shortcode');


// Wrapper for livecasinoss shortcode
function do_livecasinos_shortcode($atts, $content = "") {

    // return rendered shortcode
    return do_shortcode('[livecasinoss]');
}

add_shortcode('livecasinos', 'do_livecasinos_shortcode');
```