# Enclosing Shortcode Within Another Enclosing Shortcode Breaks Output Functionality

Tags: shortcode, hooks, actions, html

I've seen several questions on this topic, however none of them seem to actually answer the question.

I'm currently registering my shortcodes on `after_setup_theme`.

```
function mbe_register_shortcodes() {

    require_once( PATH . '/inc/shortcodes.php' );

    add_shortcode( 'font', 'mbe_shortcode_font' );

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mbe_register_shortcodes' );
```

Contents of `Shortcodes.php`:

```
/**
 * @param array       $attributes
 * @param String|null $content
 *
 * @return string
 */
function mbe_shortcode_font( $attributes = array(), String $content = null ) {

    $default_attributes = array(
        'color'  => false,
        'weight' => 'normal',
        'align'  => 'left'
    );

    $attributes = shortcode_atts( $default_attributes, $attributes );

    if ( $attributes['color'] !== false ) {
        $attributes['color'] = 'color';
    }

    $html = '' . PHP_EOL;

    $html .= '<span class="' . esc_attr( $attributes['color'] . ' font-' . $attributes['weight'] . ' text-' . $attributes['align'] ) . '">' . $content . '</span>' . PHP_EOL;

    return $html;

}
```

**Sample Text:**

```
[font align="center" weight="extra-bold"]YOUR LOCAL [font color="true"]FULL SERVICE[/font] REAL ESTATE OFFICE[/font]
[font align="center" weight="semi-bold-italic"]Our Realtors Know Real Estate![/font]
```

**With the default code specified above, the output is like:**

```
<span class=" font-extra-bold text-center">YOUR LOCAL [font color="true"]FULL SERVICE</span> REAL ESTATE OFFICE[/font]
<span class=" font-semi-bold-italic text-center">Our Realtors Know Real Estate!</span>
```

**My desired output is like:**

```
<span class=" font-extra-bold text-center">YOUR LOCAL <span class="color">FULL SERVICE</span> REAL ESTATE OFFICE</span>
<span class=" font-semi-bold-italic text-center">Our Realtors Know Real Estate!</span>
```

**#1 I've tried...**

```
$html .= '<span class="' . esc_attr( $attributes['color'] . ' font-' . $attributes['weight'] . ' text-' . $attributes['align'] ) . '">' . $content. '</span>' . PHP_EOL;

return do_shortcode( $html );
```

**#1 and outputs...**

```
<span class=" font-extra-bold text-center">YOUR LOCAL 
<span class="color font-normal text-left"></span>
FULL SERVICE</span>
 REAL ESTATE OFFICE[/font]

<span class=" font-semi-bold-italic text-center">Our Realtors Know Real Estate!</span>
```

**#2 And this...**

```
$html .= '<span class="' . esc_attr( $attributes['color'] . ' font-' . $attributes['weight'] . ' text-' . $attributes['align'] ) . '">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</span>' . PHP_EOL;

return $html;
```

**#2 and outputs...**

```
<span class=" font-extra-bold text-center">YOUR LOCAL 
<span class="color font-normal text-left"></span>
FULL SERVICE</span>
 REAL ESTATE OFFICE[/font]

<span class=" font-semi-bold-italic text-center">Our Realtors Know Real Estate!</span>
```

**#3 And this...**

```
$html .= '<span class="' . esc_attr( $attributes['color'] . ' font-' . $attributes['weight'] . ' text-' . $attributes['align'] ) . '">' . do_shortcode( $content ). '</span>' . PHP_EOL;

return do_shortcode( $html );
```

**#3 and outputs ...**

```
<span class=" font-extra-bold text-center">YOUR LOCAL 
<span class="color font-normal text-left"></span>
FULL SERVICE</span>
 REAL ESTATE OFFICE[/font]

<span class=" font-semi-bold-italic text-center">Our Realtors Know Real Estate!</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR;** Nested shortcodes cannot have the same name. You must have unique names for shortcodes within shortcodes.

I've found [the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/35210/9579) thanks to [`@patnz`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4093/patnz) in response to: [shortcode inside another shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/35208/9579).

If you look at the [WordPress Codex :: Shortcode API :: Nested Shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes) you will find the answer with an illustrative example.

So in my situation, as a quick fix, I've just added another shortcode.

```
function mbe_register_shortcodes() {

    require_once( PATH . '/inc/shortcodes.php' );

    add_shortcode( 'font', 'mbe_shortcode_font' );
    add_shortcode( 'font_color', 'mbe_shortcode_font_color' ); // Added

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mbe_register_shortcodes' );
```

**Contents of `shortcodes.php`:**

```
function shortcode_font( $attributes = array(), String $content = null ) {

    $default_attributes = array(
        'weight' => 'normal',
        'align'  => 'left'
    );

    $attributes = shortcode_atts( $default_attributes, $attributes );

    $html = '<span class="font-' . esc_attr( $attributes['weight'] ) . ' text-' . esc_attr( $attributes['align'] ) . '">' . $content . '</span>';

    return do_shortcode( $html );

}

function shortcode_font_color( $attributes = array(), String $content = null ) {

    $html = '<span class="color">' . $content . '</span>';

    return do_shortcode( $html );

}
```